# What's this amplifier filter configuration?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, audio, filter, high-pass-filter

I've come across an audio amplifier circuit that contains this following configuration:
[image]

I recognize R1,C1, and R3 to be part of a first order high pass filter, but I'm not sure what C2 and R2 are for. Does it filter high frequencies?

Comment: Where is C3? I don't see it on your schematic.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant R3

Answer (score 3):

R2 and C2 form a first order low pass filter, the cut off frequency is \$ Fc =  \dfrac{1}{ 2 \pi R C}\$  where  \$R\$ is in Ohms, and \$C\$ is in Farads, so yes, it filters high frequencies.

C1 is probably for ac coupling the opamp, which is an inverting amplifier with output\$Vout = -\dfrac{R3}{R1} * Vin\$